# How do install the LTS version of NodeJS when I already have Node 10 installed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, npm

I download Node 10.11 a few weeks back and I have a repo that requires me to have the LTS version of Node of 8.12 at the time of this question. if I download the LTS will that mess up the install I have already or will it overwrite it? I'm using a Mac with High Sierra Also without using NVM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) and have multiple versions of node on the same machine and switch by doing "nvm use version".

Comment: So can I install NVM without uninstalling the version of Node I have already on my mac?

Comment: [`nvm` gracefully works with the system-installed version](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#system-version-of-node). You don't have to uninstall anything.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment yet, but to answer your question posed to Giorgos...

"So can I install NVM without uninstalling the version of Node I have already on my mac? "

Correct. NVM allows you to install whatever versions of Node you want and switch between them whenever you want. You can also set it so certain projects run a specific Node version so you don't have to worry about switching between versions if you are jumping between projects.

This allows you to have old versions, say `0.12` for random things, but also have Node8.x.x for your one project, and Node 10.x.x for another. It is incredibly useful, and if you ever need to verify compatibility with a new version, you can install the Node version via NVM and run your tests/project with that version of node. If it works, you can stick with it, if not you can switch back and look into updating your code to work with a new version.

Comment: Thanks so much for your insight.